# Are node data stored in the render array $page?

Tags: theming

Are node data (e.g. title, body, comments) stored somewhere in the renderable array `$page`, and converted into HTML during rendering? Or does a renderable array just contain properties that indirectly cause to load particular templates files?

Where are variables that store these values printed?

[image: node]

Comment: how i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's probably in there somewhere. However, it much easier to get the current node object (if there is any) with the [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Do stuff with $node.
}
```

Comment: i asked two situation, yes to what ?

Comment: You shouldn't ask two questions. That's not how the site works. Yes is the response to the answer in the question title. For the second one, install devel.module and use dpm($node), that will tell you what's in there.

Comment: sir, i am drupal newbie can you please elaborate  this answer in simple words. please help me, rendering concept confuse me too much

Answer (score 1):

I can advice three places where you can alter node render array:

1. [hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) . Called when node is just have been loaded from DB.
2. [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) . This hook is called after node load. (As for me this is the best place to alter node render array). You can find render array in $node->content.
3. After this two hooks node render array goes to themming. You can alter node in your node template file([node.tpl.php](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)). In node tpl file variables are printed using php print. E.g.

   print render($content);

Comment: milkovsky,you explain how i alter the node data before it go for theming. but my question is what happen when line<?php print render($page['content']);?> executed in page.tpl.php that make node.tpl.php comes into play? In above picture you see node title(defui et populus)come first,then body(commodo exerci..)who define serial order of these two field? Is in render array variable that store node title, stored just above node body variable, that why it comes first or it depend upon node.tpl.php file coding structure.milkovsky if you know rendering array and template concept please help me

Comment: Of course page title and page body are separated. The order of them you can define in the page.tpl.php file. Find title string "print $title;" and "print render($page['content']);" in your_theme_folder/page.tpl.php or in modules/system/page.ptl.php. You can see that title and content are printed in different places. Change order here OR as alternative you can use "Delta blocks" module to use page title as block.

Comment: is it means node title is not part of render array $page['content']?

Comment: yes title is rendered by 'print $title' usually in <h1> tag

Answer (score 0):

yes,  A render array is an associative array which conforms to the standards and data structures used in Drupal's theme rendering system.
for more info check out: [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/930760)